# Type 'Null Function(bool)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'FutureOr<Null> Function(bool?)' because 'bool?' is nullable and 'bool' isn't

Tags: flutter, dart, boolean

this is my complete code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_yes/pages/product.dart';

class ProductCards extends StatelessWidget {


final List<Map<String, dynamic>> stuff;



 ProductCards({required this.stuff});

  Widget buildProduct(BuildContext context, {required int index}) {
    print(this.stuff);
    return Card(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Image.asset(
            stuff[index]['image']
          ),
          Text(stuff[index]['title']),
          ButtonBar(
            alignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              TextButton(
          child: Text('Details'),
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.push<bool>(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (BuildContext context) => ProductPage(stuff[index]['title'], stuff[index]['image']),
                        ),
                      
                      ).then((bool value) {

                  } ),
                  )
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

and i got this error

> 29:30: Error: The argument type 'Null Function(bool)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'FutureOr Function(bool?)' because 'bool?' is nullable and 'bool' isn't.
> ).then((bool value) {

i got the error on the line of then.((bool value) as shown

need help

Comment: `then((bool? value) {} )`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a `nullable` bool instead of `bool` in your `.then()` function like below:

```
.then((bool? value)
```